# Session Issue in my Joined Table for my Login

Tags: php, mysql, session

This photos is my 2 tables and Column,
I want to make:
 
"**firstname**" in table **members** as **$username**
 
"**password**" in table **accounts** as **$password**

for my login panel.

Here's my table and column:

[image]

My problem is this, i dont know what can i put inside the session here if i have joined table

```
if($countacc==1){
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[0];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[1];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[2];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[3];
header("location: index.php");
}
```

This is my full code:

```
<?
session_start();
include "connector.php";

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN accounts ON 
account.mem_id =members.mem_id WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";

$resultacc = mysql_query($sqlacc);
$countacc = mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
$rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_NUM);

if($countacc==1){
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[0];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[1];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[2];
$_SESSION['-------this is my problem---------']=$rowacc[3];
header("location:content/index.php");
}
else{
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Sorry if my english grammar is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
session_start();
include "connector.php";

$username   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sqlacc="
        SELECT 
            members.id AS id
            members.firstname AS username,
            accounts.password AS password
        FROM members 
        INNER JOIN accounts ON account.mem_id =members.mem_id 
        WHERE members.firstname='$username' 
        AND accounts.password='$password'";

$resultacc  =   mysql_query($sqlacc);
$countacc   =   mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
$rowacc     =   mysql_fetch_assoc($resultacc);

if($countacc    ==  1){

    $_SESSION['id']         =   $rowacc['id'];
    $_SESSION['username']   =   $rowacc['username'];
    $_SESSION['password']   =   $rowacc['password'];

    header("location:content/index.php");
}
else{
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

In your query give aliases to columns.
Instead of using mysql_fetch_array use mysql_fetch_assoc.
You should also note the use of mysql functions is depracted. You should use mysqli functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['your session name its anything what you want']=$rowacc[0];
```

means

```
$_SESSION['username']=$rowacc[0];
```

and use it where ever you want.

such as

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  //your code
}
```

examples of session:
[Introduction To PHP Sessions](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html)

[session in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's a better way to do

```
$rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

So now you can do

```
if($countacc==1){
    $_SESSION['username']=$rowacc['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$rowacc['password'];
    header("location:content/index.php");
      }
```

And you can put whatever you want      $_SESSION['here'] . It is just so you can remember and use for latter.And rest of it are same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is an array

And its `index` is user defined

So add an index `$_SESSION["myIndex"]` what you want to add an item to array `$_SESSION`

Assign value as

```
$_SESSION["myIndex"] = "My Value";
```

and use it as

```
echo $_SESSION["myIndex"];
```

Output: `My Value`

session need to start `session_start();` before using `$_SESSION`

To know more see [$_SESSION manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)